# Factors of identification vs factors of being identified vs factors to be identified

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Factors of identification
   vs
Factors of being identified
   vs
Factors to be identified

Meanings of these three phrases, and uses of those with eaxample

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of the contexts of these factors, but here's what they generally mean:

**Factors of identification**: Things that are required for identification of someone or some thing (i.e. A driver's license)

**Factors of being identified**: Not completely sure on this one. It sounds like what you learn about someone after they're identified (i.e. I looked up her info and learned that she is 6 feet tall)

**Factors to be identified**: Things that have *not* been identified yet, but will be (i.e. We will identify the gender of the child next month)